# How do I find if a library is installed in linux?

Tags: linux, shared-libraries

How do I know if a particular library is installed in Linux or not?

For example if I want to see whether the `libuuid` library is available on my system, how do I do that?

Comment: See http://serverfault.com/q/54736/200076

Answer (score 20):

One command that usually works is:

```
$ ldconfig -p | grep library
```

For instance, to check for the existence of `libuuid` you can do:

```
$ ldconfig -p | grep libuuid
```

If that doesn't work, you can always search for it manually in the usual places. It's best you run this command as the `root` user:

```
# find /lib* /usr/lib* -name '*libuuid*'
```